# How can I use gradients from SVG symbols in other files?

Tags: html, svg, linear-gradients

I have found that when I have a source SVG with a symbol and a destination SVG that access the source SVG with `<use>`, the symbol is imported and is able to access the gradient (perhaps because it is simply already on the page).  However, when the source SVG is in a different file, the objects in the `<symbol>` are imported but not the gradient.  **How can I import the gradient as well?**

Here is some MCVE code:

**index.html:**

```
<style>
  html,body,svg { width: 100% }
</style>

<!-- inline SVG with gradient -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="myDot" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 2 2">
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.133" y1="0.008" x2="0.949" y2="1.101" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0.042" stop-color="#21dbaa"/>
      <stop offset="0.358" stop-color="#00b4ef"/>
      <stop offset="0.433" stop-color="#01a7ec"/>
      <stop offset="0.568" stop-color="#0487e4"/>
      <stop offset="0.68" stop-color="#0768dd"/>
      <stop offset="0.965" stop-color="#5f1ae5"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 200 60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
  <!-- All instances of our symbol -->
  <use xlink:href="#myDot" x="5"  y="5" style="opacity:1.0" />
  <use xlink:href="#myDot" x="20" y="5" style="opacity:0.8" />
  <use xlink:href="symbol.svg#myDot" x="35" y="5" style="opacity:0.6" stroke="black" stroke-width=".1" />
  <use xlink:href="symbol.svg#myDot" x="50" y="5" style="opacity:0.4" stroke="black" stroke-width=".1" />
  <use xlink:href="symbol.svg#myDot" x="65" y="5" style="opacity:0.2" stroke="black" stroke-width=".1" />
</svg>
```

**symbol.svg:**

```
<!-- external SVG with gradient -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="myDot" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 2 2">
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.133" y1="0.008" x2="0.949" y2="1.101" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0.042" stop-color="#21dbaa"/>
      <stop offset="0.358" stop-color="#00b4ef"/>
      <stop offset="0.433" stop-color="#01a7ec"/>
      <stop offset="0.568" stop-color="#0487e4"/>
      <stop offset="0.68" stop-color="#0768dd"/>
      <stop offset="0.965" stop-color="#5f1ae5"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Here is a [working Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/bderblatter/project/editor/ABLGRK#0) that illustrates the problem, using the same code as shown above.  Notice how the two circles importing the symbol from the inline SVG in `index.html` are correctly displaying the gradient, but the three circles importing the symbol from `symbol.svg` are not displaying the gradient.

**Edit:** This may be a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752494/why-cant-i-reference-an-svg-linear-gradient-defined-in-an-external-file-paint) asking about referencing gradients in external files.

Comment: If you put the linearGradient element outside the symbol element it should work in Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson hmm...so is that just Firefox?  Is there a standards compliant/cross-compatible method?  I'm hoping to support IE11+

Comment: For IE11 I think you might need this: https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like browser support for this feature is still somewhat low ([source](https://fvsch.com/svg-gradient-fill/)).  The example given in the question should in theory work in a couple years.

One workaround is to include the gradient definitions on every page where external SVGs are referenced and point to that instead.

**index.html:**

```
<svg style="height: 0; width: 0;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.133" y1="0.008" x2="0.949" y2="1.101" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <stop offset="0.042" stop-color="#21dbaa"/>
        <stop offset="0.358" stop-color="#00b4ef"/>
        <stop offset="0.433" stop-color="#01a7ec"/>
        <stop offset="0.568" stop-color="#0487e4"/>
        <stop offset="0.68" stop-color="#0768dd"/>
        <stop offset="0.965" stop-color="#5f1ae5"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#myDot" fill="url(#linear-gradient)" />
</svg>
```

**symbol.svg:**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="myDot" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 2 2">
    <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```