# Make patch of line different color in D3

Tags: d3.js, line, visualization, data-visualization, graph-visualization

My visualization uses lines between nodes to indicate their relationship. The wider the line, the more connected the two nodes are. In this context I would like to set a small section of the lines to a darker hue to attach more information to the visualization. Whichever node is closest to the "mark" on the line is the dominant node.

Is there some command to change the color for only part of the line? Or would it be easier to create a rectangle with the same width and angle as the line?

I've attached the current visualization, where I've created some ugly little rectangles to illustrate what I'm trying to do. Also, the code is attached (although it sadly is a bit messy).

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

line {
  stroke-width: 3.5px;
  stroke-opacity: 1.0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

data = {
        nodes: [
                  {size: 200, fill: '#ffffff', line: '#8C8C8C', id: 'Me'}, 
                  {size: 30, fill: '#D2D2D2', line: '#ffffff', id: 'Bob'},
                  {size: 30, fill: '#D2D2D2', line: '#ffffff', id: 'Alice'},
                  {size: 30, fill: '#D2D2D2', line: '#ffffff', id: 'Tim Tim'},
                  {size: 30, fill: '#D2D2D2', line: '#ffffff', id: 'Mustafa'},
                  {size: 30, fill: '#D2D2D2', line: '#ffffff', id: 'Zeus'},
                  {size: 30, fill: '#D2D2D2', line: '#ffffff', id: 'McHammer'},
                  {size: 30, fill: '#D2D2D2', line: '#ffffff', id: 'Thoooor'},
                  {size: 30, fill: '#D2D2D2', line: '#ffffff', id: 'Le Viking'}
                  ],
        links: [
                  {source: 0,target: 1, calls: 20, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 2, calls: 5, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 3, calls: 8, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 4, calls: 3, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 5, calls: 2, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 6, calls: 3, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 7, calls: 5, texts:0},
                  {source: 0,target: 8, calls: 2, texts:0}
                ]
        }

var total_interactions = data.links.reduce(function(result, currentObject) {
  return result + currentObject.calls;
}, 0);
console.log(total_interactions);

var mouseOverFunction = function(d) {
  var circle = d3.select(this);

  circle
    .transition(500)
      .attr("r", function(){ return 1.4 * node_radius(d)});
}

var mouseOutFunction = function() {
  var circle = d3.select(this);

  circle
    .transition(500)
      .attr("r", node_radius);
}

function isConnected(a, b) {
    return isConnectedAsTarget(a, b) || isConnectedAsSource(a, b) || a.index == b.index;
}

function isConnectedAsSource(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}

function isConnectedAsTarget(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
}

function isEqual(a, b) {
    return a.index == b.index;
}

var line_diff = 0

function tick() {
  callLink
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x-line_diff; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y-line_diff; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x-line_diff; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y-line_diff; });
  textLink
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x+line_diff; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y+line_diff; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x+line_diff; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y+line_diff; });

  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function node_radius(d) { return Math.pow(40.0 * d.size, 1/3); } 

var width = 1000;
var height = 500;

var nodes = data.nodes
var links = data.links

var force = d3.layout.force()
              .nodes(nodes)
              .links(links)
              .charge(-3000) // -3000
              .friction(0.6) 
              .gravity(0.6)
              .size([width,height])
              .start();

var linkedByIndex = {};
links.forEach(function(d) {
  linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = true;
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

var callLink = svg.selectAll(".call-line")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("line");
var textLink = svg.selectAll(".text-line")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("line");
var link = svg.selectAll("line");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .call(force.drag);

node
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", node_radius)
  .style("fill", function(d)  {return d.fill; })
  .style("stroke", function(d)  {return d.line; })
  .on("mouseover", mouseOverFunction)
  .on("mouseout", mouseOutFunction);

svg
  .append("marker")
  .attr("id", "arrowhead")
  .attr("refX", 6 + 7)
  .attr("refY", 2)
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 4)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z");

// link
  // .style("stroke-width", function stroke(d)  {return d.calls/data.total_interactions*20; })

 var line_width_factor = 40 // width for a line with all points

 textLink
  .style("stroke-width", function stroke(d)  {return d.texts / total_interactions*line_width_factor; })
  .style("stroke", "#70C05A")

 callLink
  .style("stroke-width", function stroke(d)  {return d.calls / total_interactions*line_width_factor; })
  .style("stroke", "#438DCA")

force
  .on("tick",tick);

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: you can use css gradients.

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand a bit on that?

Comment: I've tried to follow this guide: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/applying-colour-gradient-to-graph-line.html, but the gradient is set using the object's position on the screen rather than the length of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you [can't apply CSS gradients to SVG elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956767/css-3-gradients-for-styling-svg-elements). You have to use SVG gradients.

To create an SVG gradient along a link in a graph, the general form would be:

```
defs.append("linearGradient")                
        .attr("id", gradient_id)
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("x1", source.px)
        .attr("y1", source.py)
        .attr("x2", target.px)
        .attr("y2", target.py)    
    .selectAll("stop")                      
        .data([                             
            {offset: "0%", color: "cyan"},   //color 1
            {offset: "50%", color: "cyan"},  //start the gradient from haf distance
            {offset: "100%", color: "darkBlue"} //to a darker color
        ])                  
    .enter().append("stop")         
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })   
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

In your case, the positions of `source` and `target` are changing with each `force.tick()`. So, you need to calculate and apply gradients for all links in each `tick`. By adding this line to the `tick` function:

```
callLink.each(function(d){applyGradient(this, d)});
```

Next, we need to define `applyGradient(line, d)` function:

```
function applyGradient(line, d){
    var self = d3.select(line); //select the current link

    // store the currently used gradient to delete it later.
    var current_gradient = self.style("stroke")
    current_gradient = current_gradient.substring(4, current_gradient.length-1);

    // Generate a random id for the gradient calculated for this link
    var new_gradient_id = "line-gradient" + getRandomInt();

    // Determine the direction of the gradient. In your example, you need
    // the darker hue to be near the bigger node.
    var from = d.source.size < d.target.size? d.source: d.target;
    var to = d.source.size < d.target.size? d.target: d.source;


    // Add the gradient to the svg:defs
    defs.append("linearGradient")                
        .attr("id", new_gradient_id)
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("x1", from.px)
        .attr("y1", from.py)
        .attr("x2", to.px)
        .attr("y2", to.py)    
    .selectAll("stop")                      
        .data([                             
            {offset: "0%", color: "cyan"},       
            {offset: "50%", color: "cyan"},         
            {offset: "100%", color: "darkBlue"}
        ])                  
    .enter().append("stop")         
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })   
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });   

    //apply the gradient
    self.style("stroke", "url(#" + new_gradient_id + ")")

    //Remove the old gradient from defs.
    defs.select(current_gradient).remove();
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5hd25qs/)

Comment: Strange, the fiddle doesn't work in Firefox. Anyway, thanks for the solution! How can I use variables connected to the links to set the offset? I've tried '{offset: function(d) { return Math.round(d.calls/d.texts) + "%"; }, color: "cyan"}', but get 'Error: Invalid value'.

Comment: You need to create the `data` variable beforehand, maybe using `d3.map` function. Please note that the example you gave `d.calls/d.texts` is not feasible because of the division by zero `d.texts`.

Comment: Thanks, my current version has non-zero values for `d.texts`, but it was just used as an example to see how I could access the variables. JavaScript confuses me a bit. Using `var mid_offset = Math.round((d.calls)/(d.calls+d.texts)) + "%";` above and then `{offset: mid_offset, color: "cyan"}` works. What would be the benefit of the `d3.map` function in this context?

Comment: My mistake, I forgot we are calling `applyGradient` with `d` exposed already. Your solution is fine.